# Necessary sufficient condition for correlation between last 2 out of 3 normal random variables.

Tags: probability, correlation

Consider $X,Y,Z$ all standard normal random variables. Now I also want to have some correlation between them.

Lets denote these $\rho_{XY},\rho_{YZ}$ and $\rho_{XZ}$. Surely I cannot choose them freely (on [-1,1]). Is there a necessary and sufficient condition on, say, $\rho_{XY}$ given the others? I've found the necessary condition that must lie between

$$\rho_{XY}\rho_{YZ} \pm \sqrt{1-\rho_{XY}^2}\sqrt{1-\rho_{YZ}},$$ but (simulation indicates) it  is not sufficient.

Comment: I think $\rho_{XZ}$ is missing between "that" and "must"?

Comment: You just need to ensure the resulting covariance matrix is positive definite. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Characterizations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion

Comment: Why is it not sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

My findings are that if $(\rho_{yz}, \rho_{zx}, \rho_{xy})$ lies inside the region enclosed by the symmetric parametric surface $$(x,y,z) = (\sin (\theta + \phi), \cos(\theta - \phi), \sin 2 \phi), \quad \theta \in [0, 2\pi), \quad \phi \in [-\pi/4, \pi/4],$$ then the eigenvalues of the correlation matrix $$\boldsymbol \Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \rho_{xy} & \rho_{zx} \\  \rho_{xy} & 1 & \rho_{yz} \\ \rho_{zx} & \rho_{yz} & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ will all be nonnegative, thus $(X, Y, Z)$ will be multivariate normal.

In other words, if, say, $\rho_{xy} \in [-1,1]$ is given, then $(\rho_{yz}, \rho_{zx})$ will be constrained to the interior of an ellipse whose boundary is given by the parametric equation $$(\sin(\theta + \sin^{-1}(\rho_{xy})/2), \cos (\theta - \sin^{-1}(\rho_{xy})/2), \quad \theta \in [0,2\pi).$$  You can further solve this to get an interval for one of the correlation coefficients in terms of the other two.

[image]

Comment: This is beautiful! Have you found this out yourself? - if so could you give a pointer to where to start otherwise can you provide a reference?